# What does ;; do in sh?

Tags: shell

If I try to run `a;;b` in sh, I get this error:

```
sh: <number>: Syntax error: ";;" unexpected
```

If I try `a;;;b` I get the same error, not `;;;` instead of `;;`, so I think that `;;` means something, although I don't know what does it mean.

Here is an example:

```
$ echo A;;echo B
sh: 1: Syntax error: ";;" unexpected
$ echo A;;;echo B
sh: 1: Syntax error: ";;" unexpected
$ echo A; ;echo B
sh: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

Here you can see that when I use `; ;` instead of `;;` the error is different, pertaining to the fact that I used `;` without a command before. `;;` seems to be a different operator, although I don't know what it applies to.

Comment: Can't search on Google because of the `;;`, and haven't found a dupe here.

Comment: Googled "sh double semicolon" ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905183/dash-double-semicolon-syntax

Comment: @muru Although not posted here yet I think.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That's  what SymbolHound is for symbolhound.com

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`;;` separates statements in a `case`...`esac` construct in POSIX shells:

```
case foo in (a) cmd1; cmd2 ;; (b) cmd3; cmd4; esac
```

To find out about a command, you can run `man that-command`. If your pager is `less`, you can search within the man page by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>.

Here, you'd run `man sh` and search for `;;`. Some shells support other operators to separate `case` statements (like `;&` in `ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash`/`mksh`, `&|` in `zsh`/`mksh`, `;;&` in `bash`).

Comment: I just posted here because I think there should be such a question here anyways, since here it could be explained in a clearer way if someone is confused.

Comment: If there are lots of hits, or you can't remember the escaping rules for searching with `less`, it's sometimes handy to `$ man bash|grep -C1 ';;'`

Comment: You shouldn't have `(` before `a)` and `b)`, and you need `;;` after `cmd4`

Comment: @Barmar, that syntax is POSIX. In the Bourne shell, you had to omit the `(` indeed, but you still didn't need the `;;` before `esac` (though it didn't harm).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that change in POSIX shell, or that the last `;;` was optional.